# selection in d3 svg

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm new with d3 and svg and I try to select some class to remove them.

my code is ;

```
    svgBC.append("g") 
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(30," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    svgBC.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis)
        .attr("transform", "translate(30,0)")
      .append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("Population");
```

and I want to remove the "y axis" and to keep the x one. Until there I used the method remove: `selectAll("g").remove`but now I want to keep a part of my chart...

Then, how to have a better selection to remove just a part of my draw?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works the same way as a classic CSS selector so :

use `selectAll("g.axis.y").remove()` to remove only the `g` elements with the `axis` and `y` classes.

plnkr : [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/98H1goywvxyUNKU76Q59?p=preview)

Comment: that's it
I knew it was not so difficult but didn't find the answer
Thanks!